# How do I print using html/css

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I'm trying to print a html/css page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style media="print">
        body {
                background-color: blue;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Imprime moi !</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to print, the body background isn't here. Why ?

**EDIT**
This css doesn't work anymore :

```
@media print {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Background colour is automatically removed by the browser on printing. You usually have to specifically turn it on in the print preview settings of your browser. This is not something you can do with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        body {
                background-color: blue;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Imprime moi !</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Either remove the media="print" from your style tag or use 'all' or 'screen' instead

Using this will show you the print preview mode which removes the background color from the page.